# Flutter Tooltip disappear in certain peroid

Tags: flutter, tooltip

I am trying to use Tooltip in Flutter with `triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap`. However, I don't know how to set the duration to hide the tooltip after a while. I tried waitDuration and showDuration, but seems like they did not work. Can anyone please help?

Here is the code I am using

```
Tooltip(
    message: 'Test Tooltip',
    triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
    child: Chip(
        label: Text('Test Chip'),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -4),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    )
)
```

Comment: Using `TooltipTriggerMode.tap` disables automatically removing the `Tooltip`. Tap outside the region to remove it.

Comment: Use `triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.longPress` and `showDuration` to make it disappear after a certain period.